# There is no frame but still there is an error element is not found

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is my code, the line => 
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"quote_password\"]")).sendKeys("password");` throws exception that element is not found

```
@Test
public void mytest()
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://billing.scriptinglogic.net/index.php/sessions/login");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("email");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/form/input")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Quotes']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Create Quote']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"quote_password\"]")).sendKeys("password");

}
```

Comment: Add some [wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)

Comment: @amolujagare Update the question with the relevant HTML and the error stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100);

driver.get("http://billing.scriptinglogic.net/index.php/sessions/login");
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("<EMAIL>");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("<PASSWORD>");
driver.findElement(By.name("btn_login")).click();

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[text()='Quotes']"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".create-quote"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("quote_password"))).sendKeys("password");
```

Updated based on the credentials supplied in the comment below.  I've tweaked the selectors to use ID, name and class where applicable.  There is no need to use complex XPath locators when they aren't needed.

The explicit waits are required based on the way the site is working and I've added JeffC's suggestion of using an elementToBeClickable expected condition for the input element *(I don't think it's really required in this instance though since the site doesn't seem to ever disable the input field, so a visibilityOfElementLocated expected condition is just as good really)*.

This solution is working for me in Chrome and Firefox in standard mode and Firefox in headless mode.  It's not working in headless mode in Chrome because the screen size is smaller and when the screen width goes below 1000px the header changes and the text "Quotes" is never displayed.  Below 767px the header is completely removed and you get a side menu.  This means that the flow of the script needs to change slightly based on resolution.

I would suggest asking your developer to add an ID to the menu items, it will make it easier to locate them and use the site in its various states.  The quick and dirty solution to this problem is ensure the browser is a certain size while the test runs, you can do this by setting the size in the first line of your script:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
```

When you do this it passes in Firefox and Chrome in standard and headless mode.

***Note:*** The lines with an explicit wait that result in an element being clicked are anchor elements so there is no point waiting for the element to be clickable as the condition is always going to return true.

Comment: If you are going to click them, you should be waiting for clickable.

Comment: That's another option, generally things are clickable when they are visible though. I don't normally wait until clickable unless I'm dealing with elements that don't enable until a specific action has occurred.

Comment: That Login button is an `INPUT` and `INPUT`s are generally the only element that can be disabled. If you code to visible and then your UI gets updated, you will be swapping out visible for clickable throughout your site... or you could just wait for clickable from the start and never have to worry about it. There's just no good reason NOT to from the start.

Comment: `<input>` elements are not the only one that can be disabled, it completely depends on how an app is written.  I have come across `<button>` elements, `<select>` elements and `<textarea>` elements that are disabled.  I've also seem fancy JS buttons based on `<span>` and `<div>` that assign the disabled attribute and use JS to enforce it.  I agree it's another option, but it's one I tend not to reach for unless I need it, that's my personal preference.

Comment: Right, that's why I stated "generally". I didn't mean it's the only one but to make the point that there's an `INPUT` in the example OP posted. If I remember correctly, Selenium looks for the `disabled` attribute on any element. `SPAN` and `DIV` may look (and actually be) disabled but Selenium won't detect those as disabled because of JS.

Comment: hi you can use these credentials amolujagare@gmail.com and admin123